# Android UI help

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mapview

I want to create an Android application that has a MapView at the top of the screen and a horizontal scroll view at the bottom. The data that are going to be shown on the map should be displayed at the bottom scroll view(horizontal scroll view).

Data that are current being displayed at the bottom of the scroll view will be displayed on the map as a pin. So if users scroll the bottom scroll view then the pins(represent the data on the map) will be changed associate with the data from the bottom scroll view.

I have a background with iPhone development and I am a kinda newbie for Android. Any tutorials or samples that might help for this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the android [google map tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

It will explain you how to deal with maps and markers

and [this one](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/08/mapping-with-google-apis-in-android.html) for a similar design with buttons

And in order to draw buttons on a mapview, you have to use [this trick](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg53062.html).

You will already be on the right track.

And for the list (use a list view in android), it depends where your data are from, use either a cursorAdapter (database) or arrayAdapter (memory data).

Regards,
 Stéphane